# Create page from a template with customized body

Tags: wordpress

Created a page template named page-person.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Person Page
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package mentorme
 */

get_header(); ?>  
        <div class="personality">
          <!-- dynamic content -->
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now I have added some test content, while creating the page from Template 'Person Page' like this
[image]

but on page /dr-xyz its not showing text 'Testing' anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) to display your content and [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) to display your post title. Try the following code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="personality">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <?php the_title(); ?>
           <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Read More is the more link text parameter which accepts a text string to be used as the readmore text.

Comment: Can you be more specific. What kind of output are you getting? Are you getting a complete blank screen or are you only getting the header and the footer?

Comment: I get that you are posting content and you cannot see it on the front end but i need to know what are getting at the front end? Opening the post what do you see at the front end?

Comment: No output at all! Just the html content of header and footer!

Comment: I am sorry I did not use conditionals. Check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    the_content();
  } // end while
} // end if
```